# Как регулировать высоту bxslider?

Tags: bxslider

Как регулировать высоту bxslider?

Answer (score 0):

Если подразумевается динамическая регулировка, то:

```
.sample {    
    adaptiveHeight = true;
    adaptiveHeightSpeed = 500; //скорость изменения
}
```

[Тут](https://bxslider.com/options/) подробнее.